# Automatic Data Backup on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, backup, uilocalnotification

I have an application which allows the user to backup the data on the application, it does this by converting the data into a JSON string and pushing the data to the server, where it is converted into XML and stored for when it may be needed for a data restore.

Currently the uses performs the backup manually by pressing a button.

My question is this, is it possible to implement some kind of automatic backup feature?  Whereby the application automatically backs data up everyday?

As far as I can tell the only way to implement something close to this would be to schedule a local notification alerting the user to backup their data, at which point the user would open the application and some code would run to perform the backup.

Is this as close as I can get or is there another, better, solution?

Thanks,

Tysin

Comment: why not back-up to iCloud? This is where apple is encouraging its developers to use.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there are several type of apps that are allowed to run in background (VOIP,GPS ...).

I see solution of your problem like this:
Use location background mode
Register background task by using NSTimer `UIApplication:beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`

NSTimer time should be smaller than `UIApplication:backgroundTimeRemaining`, else you have to enable and disable location manager before backgroundTimeRemaining not 0 to avoid your task killed.

This way application can be in background and perform data backup.